# Excel.Interop: AccessViolation exception when one of the parameters referes to another sheet

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I've tried to create Recordset using Excel.Interop and ExcelDNA.
I use list function to get Function Wizard dialog. So what i do:
1) I write to ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 value of that function ("=MyFunction()")
2) And then tries to run Function Wizard

```
            ...
            cell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaStr;
            if (!(bool)cell.FunctionWizard()) {
            ...
```

Function dialog starts and works fine(i can set all parameters) but when i press ok AccessViolation error occurs in case if at least one of parameters refers to another sheet.(IF everything is located at one sheet, this method works fine).
Function evaluates after pressing ok button and exception occurs on the FunctionWizard() method.
Does anyone have something similar?

---------- Update --------------

I made simple DNA Addin, with only 1 button.. and error still reproduces:
1) Function:

```
            [ExcelFunction("My Test Function")]
        public static string MyTestFunction(string param1, string param2) {
            return "It works!";
        }
```

2) Ribbon button code:

```
        public void OnButtonPressed(IRibbonControl control) {
        Application exAp = (Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;

        Range ac = exAp.ActiveCell;
        ac.FormulaR1C1 = "=MyTestFunction()";
        if ((bool)ac.FunctionWizard()) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

So when i set parameters from another sheet and press ok at function wizard, AccessViolation occurs.

Comment: Can you post more of your relevant code? Sounds like there's a reference to a sheet that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ribbon button executes code which i wrote..  MyFunction stores cell references to array and return empty value (i tried to return string and null also), MyFunction works fine, but then exception occurs..

Comment: I've also tried to simply return some string in funcions without evaluating something.. and the result was the same.

Comment: can you post all of MyFunction?

Comment: MyFunction has properties IsVolatile=false, IsMacroType=true, all of it arguments has property AllowReference=true. I've checked it without any code inside (simply return "") and this error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
I used:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Dialog dialog = app.Dialogs.get_Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogFunctionWizard);
    if (!(bool)dialog.Show()) {
```

Instead of:

```
 if (!(bool)cell.FunctionWizard()) {
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: If you shared the _really_ problematic part of the code (`FunctionWizard`) to begin with, we could have been much more helpful - and you might actually have learned something other than "I'll do it the other way then". Just sayin...